# If I fix blender physics how do I get it committed to the official release?

Tags: particles, physics

If I fix blender physics how do I get it committed to the official release?
Because for years now, it's been bothering me that blender physics is not accurate. Especially the particle physics. Next semester I am taking my second semester of physics

Physics of Electromagnetism and Optics

A broad coverage of classical electromagnetism and optics.  The areas covered include: electric charge, electric fields, electric potential, capacitors and dielectrics, DC circuits, magnetic fields, magnetic properties of matter, AC circuits, Maxwell's equations, electromagnetic waves, the nature and propagation of light, geometrical optics, and wave optics.

So, probably in the winter, I will have time and the knowledge to fix blender physics. From what I understand I need to pull it from GitHub and then build it build my computer. But what do I do after that? How do I commit it to the official release?

I am a computer science major, so I am confident that after my secound semester of physics I will be able to fix blender's physics.

Comment: If you will do this you will be blessed. You can find every information you need about this here: https://www.blender.org/get-involved/developers/ If you are a student, you can also consider signing up for Google Summer of Code - applications are open on Monday. But as far as I know after several failures during GSoC, Blender Foundation will probably be choosing smaller applications.

Comment: Have in mind that you don't just "*get it committed to the official release*", you get it **submitted**. If it aligns well with the Blender foundation roadmap and current plans for Blender development, it might then get reviewed and evaluated. If it passes the developers quality standards and criteria, and you address all the issues and comments raised it may eventually get approved for a merge.

Comment: Read https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Contents, it provides lots of info for new developers.

Comment: Fixing physics in Blender isn't just about making it more accurate, also more interactive to the users. And sometimes users don't want accuracy but artistry, so flexibility might be more useful than presets.